# Detect if a variable has been used in assignment

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a dynamic form, where the defined cells can either:

- contain a value directly inputted by the user
- be defined as a formula (input by user is disabled).

I need a way to provide a hint to the user, highlighting the cells he/she must fill to have a valid form.

In other works I could have

cellA -> input by user
cellB -> input by user
cellC -> formula = cellA + cellB
cellA and cellB are required (highlighted). This case is pretty easy to handle.

I can also have more complex formulas, call them scripts. For example

```
cellC =
    if(cellD == true)
    {
        cellC = cellA;
    }
    else 
    {
        cellC = cellB;
    }
```

I'm wondering if in javascript it would be possible to understand whether the vars cellA and cellB have been used as a right part in any assignment.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a function instead of the plain variable? Something like ```cellC = cellA()```

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can't watch for value reads of *a variable*. You could do it through accessor methods/functions or even getters of object properties.

Comment: You could just use objects for values, like `{ value: ..., kind: "formula" | "input" }` which is easy to manage and reason about.

Comment: No. The variable itself doesn't give you that information, it just holds a value. You'd have to parse your entire Javascript source code (in Javascript) to figure that out. You need one more layer of abstraction here, some form of declarative model of value interdependencies that you can parse and evaluate programmatically.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wondering if in javascript it would be possible to understand whether the vars cellA and cellB have been used as a right part in any assignment.

No, you can't hook into a *variable* being read like that.

You could make them accessor properties of an object, though, which would give you a means of doing that:

```js
const used = { a: false, b: false, c: false};
const values = { };
const cells = {
    get a() {
        used.a = true;
        return values.a;
    },
    set a(value) {
        values.a = value;
    },
    
    get b() {
        used.b = true;
        return values.b;
    },
    set b(value) {
        values.b = value;
    },
    
    get c() {
        used.c = true;
        return values.c;
    },
    set c(value) {
        values.c = value;
    }
};

// You'd only give `cells` to the code doing this, so it doesn' thave
// access to `used` or `values`.
cells.a = 2;
cells.b = 21;
const result = cells.a * cells.b;
console.log("result: " + result);
console.log("a used? " + used.a);
console.log("b used? " + used.b);
console.log("c used? " + used.c);
```

Alternatively, you could do something similar with a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Or you can store the flags and values on the object itself if you're not worried about them being accessible by other code. (Or use a class instance and [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), which are being implemented in JavaScript engines now...)

Comment: Great answer! Added a complementary answer using a Proxy

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve something like this but you'd need to use an object (as `@T.J Crowder` did in his answer) or by using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) like this

```
const grid = new Proxy({
  cellA: 'CELL-A',
  cellB: 'CELL-B',
  cellC: 'CELL-C',
  cellD: 'CELL-D'
}, {
  get (obj, prop) {
    if (prop in obj) {
      // here you can use an object or whatever you need
      // to keep track of used properties/values
      console.log(`${prop} has been retrieved.`)
      return obj[prop]
    }
  },
  set (obj, prop, val) {
    console.log(`${prop} has been set with value ${val}.`)
    obj[prop] = val
  }
})
```

Therefore doing

```
grid.cellA = grid.cellB
```

Yields

```
// cellB has been retrieved.
// cellA has been set with value CELL-B.
```

And sets the correct value of `cellB` to `cellA`